# Turn byte into array of bits? C

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I want to read binary file byte at the time and then store bits of that byte into integer array. And similarly I want to write integer array of 1s and 0s (8 of them ) into binary file as bytes?

Comment: I/O is mostly not working bit by bit. As far I know you can read byte by byte with function read and a buffer-size of 1.

Comment: You could use a bitmask of 1 and crawl along your input, but it's not really space efficient at all to turn a single bit into what is effectively 32 bits. You could try a char array to store groups of 8 bits and use bitshifting and masks to access individual bits.

Comment: Have you heard about bit shifting and bitwise operations?

Comment: What have you tried so far? If this is about C, then let's see some code, and a specific question about what isn't working. SO is not a code writing or homework service.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have an array of bytes:

```
unsigned char bytes[10];
```

And want to change it into an array of bits:

```
unsigned char bits[80];
```

And assuming you have 8 bits per byte, try this:

```
int i;
for (i=0; i<sizeof(bytes)*8; i++) {
    bits[i] = ((1 << (i % 8)) & (bytes[i/8])) >> (i % 8);
}
```

In this loop, `i` loops through the total number of bits.  The byte that a given bit lives at is `i/8`, which as integer division rounds down.  The position of the bit within a byte is `i%8`.

First we create a mask for the desired bit:

```
1 << (i % 8)
```

Then the desired byte:

```
bytes[i/8]
```

Then we perform a logical AND to clear all bits except the one we want.

```
(1 << (i % 8)) & (bytes[i/8])
```

Then we shift the result right by the bit position to put the desired bit at the least significant bit.  This gives us a value of 1 or 0.

Note also that the arrays in question are `unsigned`.  That is required for the bit shifting to work properly.

To switch back:

```
int i;
memset(bytes, 0, sizeof(bytes));
for (i=0; i<sizeof(bytes)*8; i++) {
    bytes[i/8] |= bits[i] << (i % 8);
}
```

We start by clearing out the byte array, since we'll be setting each byte one bit at a time.

Then we take the bit in question:

```
bits[i]
```

Shift it into its position:

```
bits[i] << (i % 8)
```

Then use a logical OR to set the appropriate byte;

Answer (score 0):

A simple C program to do the job on a byte array 'input' of size 'sz' would be:

```
int i=0,j=0;
unsigned char mask = 0x01u;    

for (i=0;i<sz;i++)
        for (j=0;j<8;j++)
           output[8*i+j]=((unsigned char)input[i] >> j) & (unsigned char)(mask);
```